# Absolute Value Property of Field of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I don't think my thought process is correct. Also, does 'if and only if' indicate that I should automatically resort to proof by contradiction?

Show that ${|b|} \le {a}$ if and only if $ {-a} \le b \le a$ (in the field of real numbers).

Attempt 1: Suppose that $ {-a} \le b \le a$ is not true. Then either ${b} \le -a$ or ${b} \ge a$. Consider the case ${b} \le -a$: then, $-b \ge a$... But I cannot presume that $a$ is positive here can I? This is where I am lost.

Attempt 2: If I suppose that $ {-a} \le b \le a$ is true, then $ {-a}  - b\le b -b \le a -b$. This means that $-(a+b) \le 0 \le a-b$. Then, for $-(a+b)\le 0$ to be true, $(a + b)$ must be positive. And by the first assumption, $a \ge b$. However, this does not encompass all cases, I don't think, and is not even a proper proof.

I would appreciate any input on the thoughts/statements above. Thank you.

Comment: The proper negation of the statement "$-a \le b \le a$" is that "either $b < -a$ or $b > a$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for two statements $p$ and $q$, "$p$ if and only if $q$" is equivalent to 
$$\text{(If $p$ then $q$) and (If $q$ then $p$)}$$ 
Applying this to what you want to prove, you want to show the two facts hold:

- If $|b|\leq a$ then $-a\leq b\leq a$
- If $-a\leq b\leq a$ then $|b|\leq a$.

The simplest way to go about this is to use the definition of the absolute value function:
$$|x| = \begin{cases} x, &x\geq0 \\ -x, &x<0 \end{cases},$$
and break into the two cases: $b\geq 0$ and $b<0$. To help get you started, assume that $b\geq 0$. Then, if $|b| = b\leq a$, it follows that 
$$-a<0<b\leq a,$$
which implies $-a\leq b\leq a$. Next, you need to show the same thing holds when $b<0$. After that, you need to prove the second statement, which can be shown using another case by case argument.

In general, many "if and only if" statements can be proven easily without proof by contradiction. It just comes down to knowing the definitions and important properties.

Comment: Thank you. But how come we can assume that - a ≤ b ≤ a and not -a < b ≤ a, since -a < 0 and b > 0?

Comment: We actually can state (not assume) that $-a<b\leq a$. Its just that the fact you are asked to prove is that $-a\leq b\leq a$. So we need an extra step, which is: If $-a<b$ is true, then so is $-a\leq b$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Then-- for the second statement when b < 0, if |b| = -b ≤ a , then -b > 0 < a, so b < 0 < -b ≤ a...but this cannot be simplified further?

Comment: If $-b\leq a$, then multiplying by $(-1)$ on both sides reverses the inequality, which gives: $-a\leq b$. But since $b<0<a$, we also have $b<a$ which again implies $b\leq a$. Combining the two inequalities $-a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ completes that portion of the proof.